# Does Google Analytics have any problem tracking app_offline.htm?

Tags: google-analytics, asp.net

I use `app_offline.htm` for ASP.net v4.0 to temporarily shuts the site down with a check back soon message on that page. I still want to track this page for the number of visitors.

Just curious, does Google Analytics have any problem tracking `app_offline` page particularly? In other words, could this page be tracked as a normal page?

Answer (score 1):

Serving `app_offline.htm` with IIS will result in a [503 Service Unavailable](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/55f71614-ef1b-4015-b9c8-a42c1e700c25.mspx?mfr=true) error being returned. As with other "error" status codes, Google Analytics doesn't track these by default since as they indicate, an error was returned instead of a valid page or file.

By adding tracking code to this page and your server's error pages however, you can have Google Analytics track error pages. Here are two sources to help you do this:

[Tracking Error 404 Pages and Broken Links in Google Analytics](http://blog.vkistudios.com/index.cfm/2009/4/24/Tracking-Error-Pages-and-Broken-Links-in-Google-Analytics)

[How To Track 404 Errors in Google Analytics](http://www.bluefountainmedia.com/blog/track-404-errors-in-google-analytics/)